# Inverted index given a list of document tokens using python?

Tags: python, list, inverted-index

I'm a newbie to python. I need to create an inverted index function given a list of document tokens. The index maps each unique word to a list of document ids, sorted in increasing order.

My code:

```
def create_index(tokens):
    inverted_index = {}
    wordCount = {}
    for k, v in tokens.items():
        for word in v.lower().split():
            wordCount[word] = wordCount.get(word,0)+1
            if inverted_index.get(word,False):
                if k not in inverted_index[word]:
                    inverted_index[word].append(k)
            else:
                inverted_index[word] = [k]
    return inverted_index, wordCount
```

Note: This works fine when the input argument is of the form `{1:"Madam I am Adam",2: "I have never been afraid of him"}`

output that i get for the above example:

```
{'madam': [1], 'afraid': [2], 'i': [1, 2], 'of': [2], 'never': [2], 'am': [1], 'been': [2], 'adam': [1], 'have': [2], 'him': [2]}
```

As per my code K,v correspond to Key and value of the list

Desired output when we call the create_index function with an argument:

```
index = create_index([['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c']])
>>> sorted(index.keys())
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> index['a']
[0, 1]
index['b']
[0]
index['c']
[1]
```

Comment: `[[1:'a', 'b'], [2:'a', 'c']]` is not legal python. Do you mean some sort of dictionary? Secondly, `sorted(index.keys())` should fail, as `create_index` returns a tuple, not a dict, and tuples don't have a `.keys()` method. So, please show us what you're actually using

Comment: Plus, what's index['c'] in the output? You didn't say.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget `sorted` accepts any kind of iterable; and the function is supposed to return a dictionary (an index).

Comment: @poke: `return inverted_index, wordCount` <- the function returns a tuple, which does not have a `.keys` method

Comment: @inspectorG4dget The *desired* output has little to do with OP’s attempt to solve this though :)

Comment: @poke: nuts! I didn't read it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> def create_index (data):
        index = defaultdict(list)
        for i, tokens in enumerate(data):
            for token in tokens:
                index[token].append(i)
        return index

>>> create_index([['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c']])
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'b': [0], 'a': [0, 1], 'c': [1]})
>>> index = create_index([['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c']])
>>> index.keys()
dict_keys(['b', 'a', 'c'])
>>> index['a']
[0, 1]
>>> index['b']
[0]
```

Comment: your function works. but i don't want to define index explicitly at run time, hence i've defined index= create_index(data) in the main function..but by doing this the function doesn't return the index of each element when tested..when i run the below code in console the following happens.. create_index([['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c']]) the index gets created.. but when i call index['a'] it throws an exception stating tat index isn't defined at run time..how do i rectify this ?? Please help

Comment: I don’t get what you’re saying. What do you mean with “define index explicitely at run time”? And as you can see in my code, I do `index = create_index(…)` too. The code follows your desired behavior too, so I don’t understand what you are trying to…

Comment: `create_index` returns the index, so you need to store that somewhere (e.g. in a variable `index`). Only then you can access the index with that variable; otherwise the variable would be undefined.